# Animating a progress bar to run along with a sun path study

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I often render out videos of architecture projects to show the movement of sunlight over a day with Twinmotion. I then render out a video of a progress bar in Blender to match the number of frames, as well as the time of day to give some reference to the Suns movement. This is quite tedious as I often have to completely rebuild the progress bar animation, rewriting new timestamps as well as adjusting the frame count. I then use Blender to lay the progress bar over the sunstudy and rerender them together into one video.

I was wondering if there might be a way to streamline this with geometry nodes (or other blender tools).
It would be cool if I could define the start and finish times from my sun study, define how many timestamps there should be, adjust the frame count, and it would spit out a matching progress bar.

If anyone could drop a tip, a link, or reference on how to get started on such a project (or an aspect of it), I would be much obliged!!

[image: PROGRESS BAR]

[image: FINAL RESULT]

Comment: specific problem you have and where you are stuck at.

Comment: @Chris we both have gold geonodes badges, why didn't the question close when we voted to close it? :D It seems OP doesn't request for the work to be done for him, just some starting tips, but that makes this question opinion-based; it also lacks focus, is there a specific part the OP needs help with? Sticking the progress bar to camera (just parent it to the camera), advancing the progress bar? Just scale a cuboid based on Scene time...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: I have no idea....and tbh i didn't even recognize that :D and i would love to solve/help with that question and we both could solve that (i think) but the way he asked he killed my will to help....and i didn't even downvote, just vote for close ;)

Comment: I don't understand the "discussion" here. For me, this question is perfectly fine. It boils down to this: how to create a progress bar with custom labels using Geometry Nodes - or is there another/easier way? Answer/hint: It is an easy task to create a simple progress bar in GN, but labeling might be a challenge. Idea: Maybe you can use a collection of pre-made label objects that you arrange on a mesh line. Parent the GN object in front of the camera and the overlay is done. Alternatively, you can write a small Python script that does the job.

Comment: Hi my dudes! Firstly, I was certainly not looking for someone to build this for me! Secondly, I was not aware that this forum is only there to ask a sole hyperspecific question about a problem.

Thank you to MarkusvonBroady and Blunder for the clear suggestions! That is exactly what I was hoping for by posting here!

Chris: Thank you for the suggestion to look up Erindale and Johnny Matthews for geometry node tutorials. I will definately check them out!